# URL path not working, absolute path does

Tags: php, path, fastcgi, absolute-path

I switched hosting providers and now have the following problem.

A function, `imagecreatefromjpeg()`, is trying to read a file from its URL path (http://mydomain.com/contents/category/certificate/1/template.jpg). This function was working on old setup but fails with the following error on the newer setup.

```
(104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

The problem went away once I replaced the URL path with absolute path of the same file.

The differences I can see are

1. the new setup is using nginx as Apache's reverse proxy.
2. the PHP version on new setup is 5.3.3, older setup had 5.3.14

We've tried many things but can't understand how to make URL paths work on the newer setup. Can anybody help?

Comment: You may have run into it already but in doing a little research I found [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/120150/php-5-3-2-fcgid-2-3-5-apache-2-2-14-suexec-connection-reset-by-peer-mo). It may be relevant

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess to make sure you don't have custom php handlers from your old host?

Comment: What exactly does "read a file" mean here ? Are your doing an `include()` / `require()` ?

Comment: The error above comes from the function imagecreatefromjpeg() when it tries to read the image path provided as the parameter.

Comment: The correct PHP version to be on would be 5.3.27 (and more correctly, 5.5.1, for that matter). 5.3.3 is more than 3 years old and has several security issues that were fixed in later versions. One should really not use this very old version! Especially one should not downgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you configured your nginx webserver accordingly ? Here are some good tutorials that can explain some of the more relevant nginx and php fastcgi process manager common pitfalls:

1. [Ars Technica: Web Served part 1: Setting up a web server](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/)
2. [Ars Technica: Web Served part 3: Installing PHP Fastcgi Process Manager](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/12/web-served-part-3-bolting-on-php-with-php-fpm/)
3. [Nginx common pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls)

I linked these resources because it seems as if you have a missconfiguration of your rewrite engine. In any case, please provide better context !

Answer (score 0):

try to change url 'http://mydomain.com/' by a function

```
    function selfURL(){
    $server1 = $_SERVER['HTTPS'];
    $server2 = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
    $server3 = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $server4 = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];


    $s = empty($server1) ? '' : ($server1 == "on") ? "s" : "";
    $protocol = strleft(strtolower($server2), "/").$s;
    $port = ($server3 == "80") ? "" : (":".$server3);
    return $protocol."://".$server4.$port;

    }
function strleft($s1, $s2){
return substr($s1, 0, strpos($s1, $s2));
}
print(selfURL());
```

you can replace '$port' if it not used

Answer (score 0):

i have issues with this on my server when i am running cron.

here is what i can say based on a similar topic.

1)  a page loads at something like ~/.

2)  You reference another page located at ~/../private/hello/derp.php

3)  inside derp.php it is under the assumption that you are running the file from ~/../private/hello/.'

4)  in actuality you are running it from ~/.

5)  file references are wrong because PWD is wrong.

it was annoying for my stuff to figure out but when i was looking at it in depth, i relized it was trying to load stuff from something like ~/../private/hello/images/hi.jpg where in actuality because of PWD, it was looking in ~/images/hi.jpg which didnt exist.

Maybe this helps you.  I hope it does.

**Edit** You also want to know that a lot of time, the ~/. for YOU can be different then the ~/. of PUBLIC.  That is also something to keep note of.

Try to make proper use of terminal variables via bash scripting.

Comment: You can always use the directory the current file is stored in by using the magic constant `__DIR__`, and use it to create absolute paths. That way, you wouldn't run into that trap. Also note that a cronjob does not necessarily inherit the full environment that is configured for a login shell. Usually there is only a basic setup, and any paths should rather be absolute - otherwise commands will fail because they are not found.

Comment: well damn.  Learn something new every day.  haha.  Thanks for that pointer.